# Script to Copy and paste entirerows and mergedrows?

Tags: excel, vba

The following code is the one that I'm trying to work with, but I still can't make it work with merge rows. The main idea is to create a loop to check each row from `D1:D150` and if the criteria are met then copy the entire row.

This is how my data looks like

[image]

```
Sub attributes()
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim Cel, aCell1, aCell2, aCell3, aCellAsses As Range, ws, ws0 As Worksheet
    Dim strAsses1 As Boolean
    Dim num As Integer
    '------------------------------
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Contract Attributes")
    Set ws0 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ReviewerTab")
    ws.Activate
    Set aCell1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Contract Attributes").Range("A1:A150")
    'Set aCell1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Contract Attributes").Range("D1:D150")
    'Set aCell2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Contract Attributes").Range("D:D").Find("Current Modifications", LookIn:=xlValues)
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    strName1 = InputBox("Which contract modification would you like to review?")
    num = 5
    For Each Cel In aCell1
        If InStr(1, Cel, strName1, vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, Cel, "x") > 0 Then
            Cel.MergeArea.Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Copy
    
            ws0.Activate
            Rows(num).Insert
            ws.Activate
            num = num + 1
        End If
    Next Cel
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    'ws0.Columns(4).Delete
    'aCell2.Select
    'ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
    'Sheets("ReviewerTab").Range("A5").Insert
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the merge area before "Select".
After you copy the rows, you need to count how many merged rows in the copy. I add a new variable num2 to do so. The loop cannot just simply num=num+1, it varies from what rows copied.
You may try the below code.

```
Sub attributes()
'--------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim Cel, aCell1, aCell2, aCell3, aCellAsses As Range, ws, ws0 As Worksheet
    Dim strAsses1 As Boolean
    Dim num As Integer
    Dim num2 As Integer
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Contract Attributes")
    Set ws0 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ReviewerTab")
    ws.Activate
    Set aCell1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Contract Attributes").Range("A1:A150")
    strName1 = InputBox("Which contract modification would you like to review?")
    num = 5
    For Each Cel In aCell1
        
        If InStr(1, Cel, strName1, vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, Cel, "x") > 0 Then
            Range(Cells(Cel.Row, 1), Cells(Cel.Row, Cells(Cel.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Select
            num2 = Selection.Rows.Count
            Selection.EntireRow.Copy
            ws0.Activate
            Rows(num).Insert
            ws.Activate
            num = num + num2
        End If
    Next Cel
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**TIPS**

1. To begin with, I would recommend that you see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Next you need to identify the range object that you need to copy and then copy them across.
2. `Dim Cel, aCell1, aCell2, aCell3, aCellAsses As Range` You need to declare them explicitly else the first four objects are declared as `Variant` and not `Range`.  For example `Dim Cel As Range, aCell1 As Range, aCell2 As Range, aCell3 As Range, aCellAsses As Range`
3. Do not copy the rows in a loop. It will be slow. Identify the rows you want to copy and then copy them in one go. Below is an example

**SAMPLE SCENARIO**

To demonstrate how this works, I am taking the below sample.

[image]

**CODE**

I have come up with a basic code. I have commented it so you should not have a problem understanding it. But if you do then feel free to ask :).

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet
    Dim wsOuput As Worksheet
    Dim RangeToCopy As Range
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, num As Long
    Dim searchText As Variant
    
    '~~> Row in output sheet where the rows will be copied
    num = 5
    
    '~~> Set your input and output sheets
    Set wsInput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contract Attributes")
    Set wsOuput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ReviewerTab")
    
    '~~> Take the input from the user
    searchText = InputBox("Which contract modification would you like to review?")
    
    If Len(Trim(searchText)) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    With wsInput
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Loop through the cells and check for criteria
        For i = 1 To lRow
            If InStr(1, .Range("A" & i).Value2, searchText, vbTextCompare) Then
                '~~> identify the rows you need to copy and store them
                '~~> in a range object
                If RangeToCopy Is Nothing Then
                    Set RangeToCopy = .Range("A" & i).MergeArea.EntireRow
                Else
                    Set RangeToCopy = Union(RangeToCopy, .Range("A" & i).MergeArea.EntireRow)
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
    '~~> Copy them across. You can insert them as well
    If Not RangeToCopy Is Nothing Then
        RangeToCopy.Copy wsOuput.Rows(num)
    End If
End Sub
```

**IN ACTION**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice and the script! I'll check the suggested link.